# understanding trace32 commands

Tags: debugging, embedded, trace32, lauterbach

I am looking in to trace32 cmm scripts at my work place. It is mentioned as below

```
sys.bc 1000000.
sys.m up
; disable watchdog
d.s 0x101022 0x40
d.s CPU:0x3ff00 %long 100001
d.s SD:0x101050 %long 00000051
d.s SD:0x101054 %long 5ff00002
```

My question what does following statements mean

1. sys.bc 1000000.
   sys.m up
2. d.s CPU:0x3ff00 %long 100001
   d.s SD:0x101050 %long 00000051

and another question is Where can I find reference for these commands?

Answer (score 8):

SYS.BC means SYStem.BdmClock, which is a deprecated command. Use SYStem.JtagClock instead.
SYS.M Up means SYStem.Mode Up which connects to a CPU and stops it (at reset vector if possible).

d.s means Data.Set, so D.S 0x3ff00 %long 100001 means that the debugger will write a 32bit value (100001) to the address 0x3ff00 (all hex values). %long indicates that 32bit are written.

CPU: and SD: are so called access or memory classes that allow you to select the kind of resource that shall be accesses. This is of interest in case the memory layout is not linear and an address would therefore be ambiguous.
Memory classes are described in the corresponding manual of the debugger you use.

It seems to me that at your stage it is best to have a look into one of the training documents:

http://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?training.html

Probably Debugger Basics - Training is suitable for you.

Best regards!